# Can I have a catch all route with the following route?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I have the default that vs.net creates in a MVC app:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",                                              // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
);
```

I also want to catch this route (any text after the domain name, but it can't contain a / in it i.e. no folders, just 'files' on the root).

```
www.example.com/blah
```

Answer (score 0):

This route will also match to the `www.example.com/blah` url, it will use the `blah` controller with the `Index` action.

If you want to create a specific route for `blah`, you can also do that:

```
routes.MapRoute("BlahRoute",
    "blah/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "YourControllerForBlah", action = "Index", id = "" }
);
```

Just make sure that this route is added before the default, as otherwise the default route will match first.

You can check the [ASP.NET MVC Storefront part 7](http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc-videos/video-356.aspx), for some ideas for routing, and also [ASP.NET Routing Debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/0001/01/01/url-routing-debugger.aspx) from Phil Haack.